# If the cell is empty insert in this cell 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this jquery script to view a sum of numbers from one column (all cells, which have **.iloscwarki** class)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     colSum();
});

function colSum() {
    var sum=0;
    //iterate through each input and add to sum
    $('.iloscwarki').each(function() {     
            sum += parseInt($(this).text());                     
    }); 
    //change value of total
    $('#warki2014').html(sum);
}
```

This plugin works very well but I have a problem, when some cells are empty (they contain only **.l**, without any number). How can  I edit this jquery to add  number 0 to every cells, which has the class **iloscwarki** but does not contains any number? 
I use this script with Wordpress, and this line generates cells with class **iloscwarki**

```
<td class="iloscwarki"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ilosc', true); ?> l.</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question right, try changing this line:

```
sum += parseInt($(this).text());
```

to read

```
sum += $(this).text() != "l." ? parseInt( $(this).text() ) : 0;
```

This will add the number if there is one or 0 if not.

Comment: +1 even better i guess would be: `sum += $.trim($(this).text()) != "l." ? parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) : 0; `

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore strings that don’t start with integers in your loop, it’s just a matter of checking truthiness (since `NaN` is falsy and `0` doesn’t affect the sum):

```
$('.iloscwarki').each(function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).text());

    if (value) {
        sum += value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this in the colSum() function before you add the cells value to the sum:

```
function colSum() {
    var sum = 0;

    //iterate through each input and add to sum
    $('.iloscwarki').each(function() {
        var $t = $(this);
        if(! $t.text() ) $t.text('0');
        sum += parseInt( $t.text() );
    });

    //change value of total
    $('#warki2014').html(sum);
}
```